# Akka Testkit does not work when using state variable in stub in other than last test case

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

I have a problem when using the following stub with Akka Testkit:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Status}
import akka.camel.{CamelExtension, CamelMessage, Consumer}
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestProbe}
import org.scalatest._

[import own packages]

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import scala.language.postfixOps

class ActorSpec extends AkkaTestBase
  with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike 
  with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with IOSugars {

  var stubResponse: String = ""
  var doNotRespond = false

  val stubEndpoint = "direct:test"
  val reportProbe = TestProbe()
  val actorUnderTest= TestProbe()

  // create stub consumer
  val stubConsumer = system.actorOf(Props(new Consumer {
    override val endpointUri = stubEndpoint
    override def replyTimeout = 1 second

    override def receive: Receive = {
      case msg: CamelMessage if doNotRespond => ()
      case msg: CamelMessage => sender() ! stubResponse;
      case _ => sender() ! "ack"
    }
  }), "stubActor")

  [...]
}
```

When I run the following test cases:

```
"Respond with failure when camel produces a failure" in {
  doNotRespond = true
  actorUnderTest ! // Send relevant message 
                   // (which returns the () above because of doNotRespond set to true)
  doNotRespond = false // Return to original state
  testProbe.expectMsg // Expect relevant message

"Respond with a failure when 'ERROR' status code is returned" in {
  stubResponse = readStringFromResource("/failure.xml")
  actorUnderTest ! // send relevant message
  expectMsgClass(classOf[Status.Failure])
}
```

Unfortunately this does not work. We get a timeout:

> ERROR o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: 
> xxx on ExchangeId: xxx). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: 
> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Failed to get response from the 
> actor [ActorEndpointPath(akka://xxx/stubActor] within timeout [1 second].

When the test case that changes the `doNotRespond` state variable is put as last test case everything does work.

Why is this and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Can you share the entirety of your test class?  I think that will be revealing.  If you are using `ImpliedSender` then I think I know what the issue is.

Comment: @cmbaxter I updated the question.